# Is there a way to migrate custom wordpress post types?

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I'm trying to export some custom post types from my local Wordpress environment so that other developers are able to use them without having to go through the process of adding them themselves through CPT UI and Custom Fields.

Everything I've found so far has just been about exporting posts with custom post types, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want something like being able to tell Vagrant to create a WP instance that already has a custom post type and associated custom fields already installed.

Is this doable? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a copy of your local WP installation and install on developing server with https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/.

It should take about 3-4 minutes to create a copy on the server from your localhost with this plugin.